# How to convert SQL query to Linq with GROUP BY on only date part of a datetime?

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq

Please help me to convert this SQL query to Linq

```
SELECT convert(varchar, data_acquisto,  101) as data , SUM(quantita)
FROM Acquisto 
WHERE data_acquisto >= DATEADD(month,-1,GETDATE())
GROUP BY convert(varchar, data_acquisto, 101)
```

This is what I've tried:

```
 var a = from acq in ctx.Acquisto
                    where acq.data_acquisto >= data
                    group acq.data_acquisto.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") 
                    by new { acq.data_acquisto, acq.quantita } into x
                    select new ListaGrafico() 
                    { 
                      data = x.Key.data_acquisto.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), 
                      qta = Convert.ToInt32(x.Key.quantita) 
                    };
```

This is the error I get:

> LINQ to Entities not recognizes the method 'System.String ToString(System.String)'

Comment: var a = from acq in ctx.Acquisto
              where acq.data_acquisto >= DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1)
                    group acq by new { acq.data_acquisto.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), acq.quantita } into x
                    select new ListaGrafico { data = x.Key, qta = x.Key..quantita } into x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Grouping doesn't look correct - the Sql is only grouping by the Date part of the `DateTime` column. A Linq `IGrouping` will contain all values grouped by each grouping `Key`, so no need for the anonymous grouping class.

`Convert()` will be difficult to convert from Linq to Sql, so I've materialized the data into memory after applying the predicate and done the conversion in Linq to Objects.

I'm afraid I've used the Lambda syntax:

```
var result = ctx.Acquisto
    .Where(acq => acq.data_acquisto >= DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1))
    .ToList()
    .GroupBy(acq => acq.data_acquisto.Date)
    .Select(x => new ListaGrafico 
     { 
         data = x.Key.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), 
         qta = x.Sum(acq => acq.quantita) 
     });
```

Also, if possible, I would recommend retaining the `Date` in a `DateTime` struct in preference to a `string` - this would mean changing the `data` property of `ListaGrafico` from `string` to `DateTime` and then you can omit the `.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")` in the final `Select` projection.